Excessive proxy data usage with Selenium and undetected-chromedriver
I'm developing a bot using Python 3.12.4 on Windows 10 64-bit with Selenium and undetected-chromedriver. The bot logs into a website and navigates to a specific page without performing any further actions.
I'm using a proxy, and I've noticed that this bot consumes approximately 5 times more proxy data compared to my other bots. This issue doesn't seem to be specific to undetected-chromedriver, as I've experienced the same result using Selenium-base.
For example, after 5-7 logins, it uses 50-60% of a 1GB proxy. Most of my other bots are written using the requests library, and I've never seen such high proxy usage with them.
Important note: I'm not using headless mode in my bot, and I haven't tested the proxy usage with headless mode enabled.
Here are the details:

Python version: 3.12.4
OS: Windows 10 64-bit
Libraries: Selenium with undetected-chromedriver (also tried Selenium-base)
Browser: Chrome (non-headless mode)

I'm trying to understand the cause of this excessive data usage and how I can optimize it. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any ideas on how to reduce the proxy data consumption?
Any insights or solution suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Should I consider testing with headless mode, or are there other configurations I should look into?
I've tried both Selenium with undetected-chromedriver and Selenium-base, but encountered the same issue with excessive proxy usage in both cases.

I'm not using headless mode in my bot, and I don't believe switching to headless mode will solve the problem.

I expected the proxy usage to be similar to my other bots, which use significantly less data for similar operations.

probably calls from driver managers.  What URLs are consuming the most data?

I use the google login page and the link to any business on google maps. I use 2 urls in total. I only open 1 driver

I meant in the proxy's logs of traffic going through it...

Total
optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com
1.47 GB

I think that's for Chrome updates.  (they download in the background)  Using an up-to-date browser should fix that for a little while... you can also turn off auto-updates in browser settings.

try this
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--no-first-run");
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=OptimizationGuideModelDownloading,OptimizationHintsFetching,OptimizationTargetPrediction,OptimizationHints");


Explain what the code does.
